# HTML Full Gutter Space

Tags: html, css

How come 2em is called a full gutter space? Take look at the declarations below by the html framework. Also why use em's?

```
.left-padding {
    padding-left: 2em;
}

.xlarge-left-padding {
    padding-left: 2em;
}

.double-left-space {
    margin-left: 4em;
}

.xlarge-double-left-space {
    margin-left: 4em;
}
```

Comment: Not sure on "full gutter", but in general em's are relative to the font size, so you can design around a static or dynamic font size.

Comment: "How come 2em is called a full gutter — By whom? In what context? Gutter sizes can be whatever you want them to be.

Comment: "Also why use em's?" — In general? There's bound to be a question on SO about the benefits of the em unit. In that code specifically? That would either be the same duplicate or it would be asking us to give you our opinions of what the author of that code was thinking.

Comment: ink interface kit by sapo calls 2 em a full gutter, so there's no such standard?